# Error: error converting data type varchar to numeric

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, sql, datetime

I am trying to insert into the database a string of  the current time:

```
string tm = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
string sql = string.Format("INSERT INTO Kabala1 (Nu_kabala,Ma_num,Date,Time,Total,Status,Name,User_n) VALUES('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}','{7}')", n, Session["Ma_num"], now, tm, lprice, "sdfsdf", Session["user"], "sdfsdf");
```

But when I run the code above I get the error: error converting data type varchar to numeric.

How do I solve it?

Comment: You need to identify the columns on your table that are of numeric type (i.e. `int`) and remove corresponding `''` characters of the `INSERT`.

Answer (score 0):

One or more of the column data types that you're inserting into is numeric, however you are wrapping all of the values you insert in single quotes (`'`). This means that when the value is inserted, it will try to cast an `varchar` (the value you wrapped in single quotes) as a numeric value, and fail.

You need to identify which of the values you are trying to insert is numeric, and remove the single quotes from it within the insert statement.

For example:

```
string.Format("INSERT INTO Kabala1 (Nu_kabala,Ma_num,Date,Time,Total,Status,Name,User_n) VALUES('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}',{4},'{5}','{6}','{7}')", n, Session["Ma_num"], now, tm, lprice, "sdfsdf", Session["user"], "sdfsdf");
```

Where {4} is numeric.